# How can I view the source code of the last example of Classify?

Tags: documentation, machine-learning

[image]

The last example of `Classify` 's documentation is: draw in the box to test a logistic classifier trained on the dataset.
In general, we can easily viwe the code in documentation, can some body tell me is it possible to view it's code and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) to the contents of the documentation cell to see the input code:

[image]

The code is too long to reproduce here.